# When does Java if statement exit?

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a function when has an if-else statement. It essentially looks like this:

```
if(boolean == true)
{
    // do something
    boolean = false;
}

else if(boolean == false)
{
    // do the other thing
    boolean = true;
}
```

Now, my understanding is that the if statement will exit and return control to the function and then continue according to the changed boolean value. But I'm clearly missing something because my code is not exiting the original 'if'/'else if' statement (whichever the original case). Can anyone tell me what I've missed?

Well as requested, additional data about the code is that it is a part of my android project and each condition in the if-else block has a nested function and the boolean(global) value is being set/unset withing these functions. So the code now looks like this:

```
dummyFunction(){

boolean = checkIfTrueOrFalse();

if (boolean) {

onClick( public void onClick(){

     // do something

boolean = false;}

} else if(boolean == false){

   onClick( public void onClick(){

     // do something

boolean = true;}

}
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It surely will exit, the question may rather be at which point will it exit?

Comment: What is happening instead? Can you provide an example which compiles and we can run to see the problem?

Comment: Side note: `if (b == true)` is ugly. Simply use `if (b)`. Similarly, `if (b == false)` is ugly. Simply use `if (!b)`

Comment: In an `if else` construction, there will _always_ be one path chosen. Either the `if` case or the `else` case. Not both or none! If you want to understand better, try inserting some `System.out.println(...)`.

Comment: How are you expecting the program to flow?

Comment: I have a button which, when clicked, will change the boolean value and I want the onClick() function to exit and return control to the main function so that the appropriate if-condition is chosen thereafter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(boolean == true)
{
    // do something
    boolean = false;
}

if (boolean == false)
{
    // do the other thing
    boolean = true;
}
```

When you do this, then the program will flow to the second condition. In an if/else if statement, if the `if` statement has been satisfied, then the program will ignore the `else if` block.

Your current code simply flows through the first `if` block and then skips the `else if` statement to end the block.

Comment: Please take a look at the information I've added to my original question. The situation will hopefully get clearer.

Comment: Thanks I took your advice and changed the else if to if and it worked better. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
void someMethod()
{
    boolean aBoolean = true;
    if(aBoolean == true) 
    {     
        // do something     
        aBoolean = false; 
    }  
    else if(aBoolean == false) 
    {     
        // do the other thing     
        aBoolean = true; 
    }
}
```

When `someMethod` will execute, since `aBoolean` is assigned with `true`, control will come to `if` block cause the condition becomes true. if it was `false`, then the control will come to `else` part.

Comment: @Azodious.. Why not just use `if(aBoolean)`?? And we really don't need an `else-if`.. Just `else` will do..

Comment: Yes, but the purpoose was to make OP understand the concept of `if-else` flow.

Comment: @Azodious.. Yeah I know.. I am not offending the solution in any way.. Just wanted to quote it to you..

Answer (score 1):

We have many good answers/comments already but just wanted to add something here -

1.

```
if (condition) {
} else {
}
```

is a single code construct. The condition will be evaluated at the beginning at run time and java will decide which block to execute i.e. the **if** block or the **else** block. **Only 1 of the 2 can be executed.**

2. Java allows us to nest **if/else**. That means we can have something like below -

   if(condition1){ 
   } else if (condition2) { 
   } else if (condition3) { 
   } else { 
   }

It is effectively same as below -

```
if (condition1) {
} else {
  if (condition2) {
  } else {
    if (condition 3) {
    } else {
    }
  }
}
```

Here, it should be noted that only the block which satisfies the condition will be executed. If none of the conditions is met, then the inner most **else** will be executed (i.e. the **else** block of *condition3* )

3. Finally, I feel that your confusion is between the below blocks

   boolean aBoolean = true;
   if(aBoolean == true) 
   {
     // do something
     aBoolean = false; 
   }  else if(aBoolean == false) 
   {
     // do the other thing
     aBoolean = true; 
   }

*VS*

```
boolean aBoolean = true;
if(aBoolean == true) 
{     
  // do something     
  aBoolean = false; 
}  

if(aBoolean == false) 
{
  // do the other thing
  aBoolean = true; 
}
```

In the latter of the 2 examples, there are 2 independent **if** blocks and both will get executed (off course, this is not logically correct but it is a legal java code.)

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide more info regarding your code not exiting either of the 2 blocks? Doing System.out.println() of variables within your blocks might be able to help you determine why your code is not exiting.

You could use an if/else pair instead of an if/else-if as the parameter that your code depends on is would be either true/false. If the if-block is not satisfied, automatically the else-block would be traversed.

Comment: I've added information to my original question. Please take a look.

Comment: I just noticed, you used boolean as an identifier/variable, and the Java tag is included in your original post. If indeed your code is for Java, boolean is considered a reserved word as it is a primitive data type, thus should not be used as an identifier in Java programs.You might want to consider using a different identifier aside from boolean.

Comment: I know that. :) I'm actually using a different variable name in my actual program. This was just conceptual. I didn't mean for you to take it literally. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually a shortcut for

```
if (boolean) {
    // do something
    boolean = false;

} else {

    if (!boolean) {
        // do the other thing
        boolean = true;
    }
}
```

Written this way, it maybe becomes clearer that the inner `if` nested in the `else` case will not be processed if the first `if` condition was already met.

Comment: Why you need that `inner-if` at all??

Comment: You're right, it is redundant. Yet the OP's code contained it, and IMHO his question focussed on the `if/else` construct.

Answer (score 0):

Well I've solved it (taking inputs from here of course). I just added a call to the function within the nested functions and it worked. Now the code looks like this:

```
public static void dummyFunction(){

boolean = checkIfTrueOrFalse();

if (boolean) {

onClick( public void onClick(){

 // do something
 dummyFunction();

boolean = false;}

} else if(boolean == false){

   onClick( public void onClick(){

 // do something

dummyFunction();

boolean = true;}

}
}
```

Comment: All right. But please remove the `if(boolean == false)`, it's superfluous. Just `} else {` will do and is much clearer.